# How to assign custom font to parsed data in a listView?

Tags: android, listview, jsoup, custom-font

I just parsed some data with jsoup and showed them in listview
but i want change the font for parsed data?
shall I create a custom lv?
how?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, titleList);
}

public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://tinyez.net//").get();
            title = doc.select("div.post.lit");
            title1 = title.select("h2");
            for (Element titles : title1) {
                titleList.add(titles.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a folder with name "folder" in "assets" folder.

Step 2: Download the font which you want to apply to text(file should be in .ttf format).

Step 3: From MainActivity add the String to List and pass it to CustomAdapter and add adapter to ListView.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
List<String> listString ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
            "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2"};
    listString = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length;i++){
        listString.add(stringArray[i]);
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,listString);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

}

Step 4: Create class CustomAdapter and extends it with ArrayAdapter and do the under mention code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

List<String> listString;
Activity context;
Typeface typeFace ;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<String> listString) {
    super(mainActivity,R.layout.list_row,listString);
    this.context=mainActivity;
    this.listString=listString;
}
static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(vi==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/verdana.ttf");
    holder.textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    holder.textView.setText(listString.get(position));

    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: would you give me more detail?

Comment: 03-04 21:33:16.566: E/ArrayAdapter(14443): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView

Comment: 03-04 21:33:16.571: E/AndroidRuntime(14443): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: give @+id to your text view in xml, if it do not work than give me your email id, ill give you dummy project for changing font of text view in list view.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a custom `ListView` Adapter. In `getView()` you'll be able to set the type face of your `TextView`.

See this on how to write a custom adapter: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html